# Replacing images inside "Code" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Im trying to replace all of the smiley images with there plain text on this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/44mqG/4/

As you can see im trying to use:

```
$("code").each(function () {
    var a = ['<img class="smile" src="http://static.yamma.org/images/icons/smile.png">', '&lt;img class="laugh" src="http://static.yamma.org/images/icons/laugh.png"&gt;'],
        b = [":)", ":D"],
        inner = $(this).children('img').size();
    for (var d = 0; d < inner; d++) {

        var c = $(this).html();
        var e = c.replace(a[d], b[d]);
        $(this).text(e)
    }
});​
```

But this replaces only the first smiley of each image.
Then after the already replaced smileys the none replaced ones return:

```
&amp;amp;lt;img class="smile" src="http://static.yamma.org/images/icons/smile.png"&amp;amp;gt; &amp;amp;lt;img class="laugh" src="http://static.yamma.org/images/icons/laugh.png"&amp;amp;gt;
```

I don't see why its adding the &amp;lt;

Is there a solution for this? Does anyone have another idea how to replace certain smiley images into their plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    switch($(this).attr('class')){
        case "smile":
            $(this).replaceWith(':)');
            break;
        case "laugh":
            $(this).replaceWith(':D');
            break;
    }   
});
```

and here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44mqG/4/)

Answer (score 1):

To address the final part of your question, that of an alternative approach, may I offer you:

```
var emotions = {
    'smile' : ':)',
    'laugh' : ':D'
};

var img = $('code img').each(
    function(){
        var s = this.src.split('/').pop(),
            emo = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf('.'));
        if (emo == 'laugh' || emo == 'smile'){
            console.log(emotions[emo]);
            $(this)
                .replaceWith('<span class="emotion">' + emotions[emo] + '</span>');
        }
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/44mqG/8/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to replace the whole image tag or put the text smiley as the text of an image tag? I'm not sure that the second option makes much sense, but it looks to me like what your code is doing. Here's some code that does that: http://jsfiddle.net/44mqG/5/

Here's code that replaces the whole tag with new span tags: http://jsfiddle.net/44mqG/6/

Answer (score 0):

> But this replaces only the first smiley of each image

`String.replace` works this way. In order to replace all occurences, you need either to replace by `RegExp` with global flag (`g`) set on, or do it in a loop.

> I don't see why its adding the &amp;lt;

Becuase you're getting that as html (`var c = $(this).html();`), and writing back as text (`$(this).text(e)`)